# Is my build script for targeting multiple target frameworks working correctly?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-2012, .net-4.5

I wrote a little MSBuild script to build my project on multiple versions. When I run it from VS2012 Command Prompt it works, I don't get any errors or exceptions. However when I compare the produced assemblies, they are identical. Is there something wrong in my script?

```
<Target Name="Build">

  <MSBuild Projects=".\WcfClientBase\WcfClientBase.csproj" 
           Properties="Configuration=Release;OutputPath=.\BuildArtifacts\net45;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5" />

  <MSBuild Projects=".\WcfClientBase\WcfClientBase.csproj"
           Properties="Configuration=Release;OutputPath=.\BuildArtifacts\net40;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.0" />

  <MSBuild Projects=".\WcfClientBase\WcfClientBase.csproj"
           Properties="Configuration=Release;OutputPath=.\BuildArtifacts\net35;TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5" />

</Target>
```

I have VS2012 Professional installed. I also noticed .NET 4.5 doesn't have its own MSBuild.exe. Is it using the one from version 4.0?

**Update**

I built it with Visual Studio for each version and all assemblies are different. There is something wrong with my script. I deliberately mistyped the TargetFrameworkVersion parameter name but it still built and produced same outputs. Maybe it's unable to override that parameter from the project file or there are other parameters I am missing. Any more ideas?

Comment: I just use ILMerge to change a .NET 2 executable to .NET 4 ;p Remember, the entry point dictates the runtime version. In my case all assemblies are built targeting .NET 2 and using AnyCPU. Then I use ILMerge and corflags to generate a set of 4 executables for .NET version and bitness combinations. Works a charm (in my case specifically for using ngen on all 4 those configurations).

Comment: How are you doing your comparison?  Are you comparing byte-for-byte?

Comment: If you change the target framework and rebuild in Visual Studio, do you get the same binaries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need to customize IntermediateOutputPath property, otherwise all 3 flavors share the same intermediate directory `obj\Release`. Try this:

```
<Target Name="Build"> 
     <MSBuild Projects="WcfClientBase\WcfClientBase.csproj"  
         Properties="Configuration=Release;OutputPath=BuildArtifacts\net45\;IntermediateOutputPath=obj\Release\net45\;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.5" /> 
     <MSBuild Projects="WcfClientBase\WcfClientBase.csproj"  
         Properties="Configuration=Release;OutputPath=BuildArtifacts\net40\;IntermediateOutputPath=obj\Release\net40\;TargetFrameworkVersion=v4.0" /> 
     <MSBuild Projects="WcfClientBase\WcfClientBase.csproj"  
         Properties="Configuration=Release;OutputPath=BuildArtifacts\net35\;IntermediateOutputPath=obj\Release\net35\;TargetFrameworkVersion=v3.5" /> 
 </Target>
```

Comment: Didn't help. Assemblies are still identical.

Comment: @Ufuk, compare 3.5 binary with 4.0. They will be different. One way to compare is open up the binary in `ildasm` and check which version of mscorlib is linked in assembly metadata.

Comment: @Ufuk, I confirmed the script built different binaries on my machine. I can see for 3.5 it linked against mscorlib v2, while for 4.0 and 4.5 it linked against mscorlib v4. Remove all your intermediate files under `obj` and try again.

Comment: +50 (when StackOverflow will let me in 24hrs), helped me solve this http://stackoverflow.com/a/16825955/637783