# Produce a .NET 4.0 library from a PCL Project where code is identical

Tags: c#, msbuild, .net-4.0, portable-class-library

It's quite frustrating, I have a Portable Class Library (PCL) library that had to drop .NET 4.0 in the profile to have access to the right API's "in PCL land". However, these API's do exist in .NET 4.0, such that if the exact same code is in a .NET 4.0 project it compiles just fine.

I want a minimal ongoing maintenance way to recompile the code in this PCL project to .net 4.0 so I can include it in a Nuget package.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With minimal conditional adjustments to the `.csproj`, an msbuild project can be created to compile a portable library solution to produce additional .net 4.0 profile binaries.

### Build.proj:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <ItemGroup> 
        <ProjectToBuild Include="MyPortableSolution.sln">
            <Properties>Configuration=Release;</Properties>
        </ProjectToBuild>
        <ProjectToBuild Include="MyPortableSolution.sln">
            <Properties>Configuration=Release;OutputPath=bin\Release.net40\;IntermediateOutputPath=obj\Release.net40\;UseNet40=true;</Properties>
        </ProjectToBuild>
    </ItemGroup>
    <Target Name="Build">
        <MSBuild Projects="@(ProjectToBuild)"/>
    </Target>
</Project>
```

### Make changes in two areas of MyPortableProj.csproj:

**First** Replace:

```
<TargetFrameworkProfile>Profile46</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

With:

```
<UseNet40 Condition=" '$(UseNet40)' == '' ">false</UseNet40>
<TargetFrameworkProfile Condition="$(UseNet40) == false">Profile46</TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

**Second** Replace:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
```

With:

```
<Import Condition="$(UseNet40) == true" Project="$(SolutionDir)\refs.targets" />
<Import Condition="$(UseNet40) == true" Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
<Import Condition="$(UseNet40) == false" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft\Portable\$(TargetFrameworkVersion)\Microsoft.Portable.CSharp.targets" />
```

### Include a `refs.targets`

This is a file with the assembly references you need *(edit from project to project)*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="mscorlib" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

*note: using a separate file because Visual studio parses and displays it otherwise.*

### msbuild Build.proj

This will create your portable lib in `bin\Release` and .net 40 specific lib in `bin\Release.net40`

Answer (score 3):

I guess there isn't a 'one size fits all' answer to this problem.

As a first step, it might be useful to try the [pcl analyser](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/vagif/archive/2013/02/05/check-your-code-portability-with-pcl-compliance-analyzer.aspx) in order to see how many types and methods fall outside of a 4.0 profile

- if it's only a few methods then you might be able to find a way forwards using a lower profile pcl alongside a small number of platform specific abstractions.
- but if there are a lot of incompatibilities then you may need to find some file-linking or project file transforming solution.

Comment: -1 This is not an answer to my question, as stated my project compiles fine for .net 4.0 and PCL(.net45, SL4, WinRT), just separately. I'm asking for a low maintenance way to compile for both when there are zero code differences between the PCL and the .net40.

Comment: thanks for the downvote... actually it is an answer to your question. But if you don't understand, then I guess that can't be helped. Over and out.

Comment: adding platform abstracts increases maintenance, I do understand your answer, and downvotes really aren't personal.

Comment: Your question asked for low maintenance solutions. My answer offers two suggestions which minimise maintenance. These are based on my experience in working with PCLs during construction of large PCL-based projects using mvvmcross. These answers may not have been as low maintenance as you hoped - it sounds like you actually will downvote any answer which isn't zero-maintenance - but they are still both valid answers to your question.

Comment: This answer would be improved if it described or referenced a project file transforming solution.